# Birational elliptically fibered variteties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Does anyone know any example of two elliptically fibered toric variety (3-fold) that are birational to each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Over $\mathbb{C}$ all toric varieties are rational, hence any two (of the same dimension) are birational. Many examples of toric 3-folds with elliptic fibrations are given in the following paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.4883.pdf.